# concurrent session in oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

I want to have an application linked to oracle database the users will request data through the app and the app will access the database and retrieve the info. my question is how many concurrent session the system will support?

Comment: Tons, depending on your hardware.  Even more if you're in a shared server instead of a (more common) dedicated server configuration.  Your application code is far more likely to be the concurrency bottleneck than the Oracle database is.  But this is a question for the DBA StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

1 to 2^16 sessions depend on setting in `V$RESOURCE_LIMIT` where `RESOURCE_NAME = 'SESSIONS'`.
Default setting is depend on number of cpu cores and process limits.

There is also limitation by OS tcp stack. Each tcp connection eating minimum 4096B + 4096B r/w buffer and some data for internal structure. So 1000 connections also mean you need minimum 8MB RAM.

Oracle also reserve some memory for each session. It's called PGA. When you expect thousands sessions you should do some magic tuning :).

Another limitation is Oracle licence. Have a look to `V$LICENSE`.